# Expression-like (lambda?) property syntax

Tags: c#, syntax, properties, c#-6.0

Recently I saw a *strange* syntax of property

```
public bool IsEnabled => control.IsEnabled;
```

Question: **How this thing is called?** I've failed to find a proper name for it and therefore can't find it to read about it.

---

Some tests proves it behaves as a property without setter:

```
bool TestA { get; set; }
bool TestB => TestA;

TestA = false;
Console.WriteLine(TestA); // false
Console.WriteLine(TestB); // false
TestA = true;
Console.WriteLine(TestA); // true
Console.WriteLine(TestB); // true

Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(TestB),
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)?.CanWrite); // false
```

Comment: `Expression Bodied Functions and Properties`

Comment: Or more generally, it's an "expression-bodied member".

Comment: are you sure about the output?

Comment: @AntiHeadshot, my bad, fixed.